# How can I get Letsencrypt certificates before adding the server to production

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, ca

I am trying to lunch new servers automatically when needed but I am having some difficulty getting the certificate before making the server live. What I want to do is run a setup script which gets all the packages, websites and certificates ready and after that add the server to production. However, Letsencrypt wants me to verify that the server requesting the certificate is actually the website which replies to requests. How can I get the Letsencrypt certificate before adding the server to production? I don't want requests to the real website to be routed to the new server until it is fully setup and has the certificates.

One solution I thought of is to save the certificates on an AWS S3 bucket and synchronize them whenever a renewal is needed. Then when I setup a new server I just get the latest certificate from my AWS S3 bucket and I don't have to worry about getting the certificate from the CA until after the server is added to production.But this solution doesn't seem "clean" and would require me to have an S3 bucket just for my Letsencrypt certificate which also adds another weakness where a certificate could be stolen from.

Is there a more simple solution which I haven't thought of yet?

Comment: Are these servers all serving the same domain, or different domains?

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that the LE certificate acquisition process takes a few seconds, typically.  Are you sure this race condition is actually a problem in practice?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I have 1 server serving multiple domains. I plan on having a pool of servers with a load balancer setup soon though.

Comment: If you have multiple servers serving the same domain(s), then they need to share certificate(s) - you don't need to get a new cert for each server (indeed, it wouldn't really make any sense to do so).  You might want to simplify things by terminating HTTPS at your load balancer.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth A few seconds on a popular site can mean many users getting a reply from the site without a certificate. I would say it can be important

Comment: I think you're conflating two different problems - (A) getting the cert for a (new) domain for the first time, and (B) adding a new server to a pool (that already has a cert).  If (B) is the real problem, then there's no need to interact with LE.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth My problem is B. I want the certificate for a site which already has a certificate but on a new server. My concern is whether it is best to get the certificate from the CA or if I should store the certificate somewhere like an AWS S3 bucket and get it from there whenever I want to setup a new server

Answer (score 1):

In a load-balanced (LB) scenario, you should consider having exactly one entity responsible for performing LE certificate acquisition.  Things get complicated with multiple entities doing this asynchronously - you'd need to be able to guarantee that the [ACME challenges](https://letsencrypt.org/how-it-works/) get routed to the relevant server(s), and your LB doesn't have that information (without additional complexity).

So I'd suggest either:

1. Terminating HTTPS at your load-balancer.  Then none of your servers need to care about HTTPS or certificates.
2. Having one "special" server that's responsible for interacting with LE, and then distributing the cert to the other servers.  The details of how you do that is implementation-dependent, because it depends on how you're managing server/service configuration.